# string numbers sorting in WPF listview

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview, sorting

This code has some small issue

```
listView1.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("id",
        ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

Sorts this string numbers: 22,20,3,5,8,10,12,14,17,2,1 into:
1,12,14,17,2,20,22,3,5,8

Could anybody share an idea how to make a "normal" sorting?

Comment: Coud you change your id property into int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your `id` column an integer or string type? If it's a string type, the listview is sorting the strings correctly. In a nutshell, it checks each character of each string from left to right.

If you change the `id` column to an integer type, it will sort them the way you expect.